# How to get a matplotlib Axes instance

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis

I need to make a candlestick chart using some stock data. For this I want to use the function [matplotlib.finance.candlestick()](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/finance.py). I need to supply quotes to this function and "*an Axes instance to plot to*". I created some sample quotes as follows:

```py
quotes = [(1, 5, 6, 7, 4), (2, 6, 9, 9, 6), (3, 9, 8, 10, 8), (4, 8, 8, 9, 8), (5, 8, 11, 13, 7)]
```

I now also need an Axes instance though, at which I am a bit lost. I created plots before using `matplotlib.pyplot`. I now need to do something with [matplotlib.axes](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html) though, but I am unsure what exactly.

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Use the [`gca`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gca.html?highlight=gca#matplotlib.pyplot.gca) ("get current axes") helper function:

```
ax = plt.gca()
```

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.finance
quotes = [(1, 5, 6, 7, 4), (2, 6, 9, 9, 6), (3, 9, 8, 10, 8), (4, 8, 8, 9, 8), (5, 8, 11, 13, 7)]
ax = plt.gca()
h = matplotlib.finance.candlestick(ax, quotes)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 23):

You can either

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()  #create figure and axes
candlestick(ax, quotes, ...)
```

or

```
candlestick(plt.gca(), quotes) #get the axis when calling the function
```

The first gives you more flexibility. The second is much easier if candlestick is the only thing you want to plot

Answer (score 2):

Every Figure instance has Axes defined on it. As the other answers mentioned, `plt.gca()` returns the **current** Axes instance. To get other Axes instances defined on a Figure, you can check the list of Axes in the Figure through the `axes` property of the Figure.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(3))
plt.gcf().axes     # [<Axes: >]


fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3)
fig.axes   # [<Axes: >, <Axes: >, <Axes: >]
```

This returns a list, so you can just index it for the specific Axes you want.

---

This is especially useful if you create a plot using a library that doesn't obviously return an Axes instance. As long as said library uses matplotlib in the background, every plot has a Figure instance, through which any Axes in it can be accessed.

For example, if you plot seasonal decomposition using `statsmodels`, the returned object is a matplotlib Figure object. To change something on any of the subplots, you can use the `axes` property. For example, the following code makes the markersize smaller on the residual plot in the decomposition.

```py
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
# plot seasonal decomposition
data = pd.Series(range(100), index=pd.date_range('2020', periods=100, freq='D'))
fig = seasonal_decompose(data).plot()

fig.axes  # get Axes list
# [<Axes: >, <Axes: ylabel='Trend'>, <Axes: ylabel='Seasonal'>, <Axes: ylabel='Resid'>]

ax = fig.axes[3]               # last subplot
ax.lines[0].set_markersize(3)  # make marker size smaller on the last subplot
```

[image: result]