# Get axis from stem plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to modify the axis of a stem plot, e.g. to change the grid color with `ax.grid(color='gray', axis='y')` in the stem plot [example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/stem_plot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-stem-plot-py). How would I do that?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# returns 10 evenly spaced samples from 0.1 to 2*PI
x = np.linspace(0.1, 2 * np.pi, 10)

markerline, stemlines, baseline = plt.stem(x, np.cos(x), '-.')

# setting property of baseline with color red and linewidth 2
plt.setp(baseline, color='r', linewidth=2)
```

[image: stem plot]

Comment: All plotting functions in matplotlib return an artist or tuple of artists. The only pyplot functions that return an axes are those that also create an axes, `plt.subplots()`, `plt.subplot`, `plt.axes()`, and `plt.gca()`. Here `ax = plt.gca()` can be used. In that sense it's probably a duplicate of [How to get a matplotlib Axes instance to plot to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067668/how-to-get-a-matplotlib-axes-instance-to-plot-to)?

Comment: Thanks, I revised my question. I was mistaken as I typically use `pandas` plotting, which returns an axis but doesn't make stem plots available.

Comment: @Sheldore thanks for the reminder, and for your answer which I accepted. I am not new to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can just use `plt` without defining `ax`. Although I prefer the latter (your answer).

```
plt.grid(color='gray', axis='y')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First define the axis using `plt.subplots()`, then call as `ax.stem` rather than `plt.stem`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
markerline, stemlines, baseline = ax.stem(x, np.cos(x), '-.')
ax.grid(color='gray', axis='y')
```

[image: stem plot with gridlines]

Answer (score 0):

Per [How to get a matplotlib Axes instance to plot to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067668/how-to-get-a-matplotlib-axes-instance-to-plot-to), another option is adding this at the end:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.grid(color='gray', axis='y')
```

[image: resulting plot]

(ht ImportanceOfBeingErnest)